# Calling JavaScript functions in a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I don't know if what i want to do is possible, but I have a JavaScript library i would like to use in the Server end of my Blazor app. Specifically in a service class.

My Blazor app has 2 environments, a Client and a Server. I am able to call my JavaScript functions on the client end using wwwroot/index.html and a blazor component, but i'm not sure how to go about doing it in the Server end. A lot of the documentation suggest providing the JavaScript function in Pages/_Host.cshtml but my project doesn't have (it has only Pages/_Layout.cshtml)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *wwwroot/index.html* and you don't have *Pages/_Host.cshtml* means you are using Blazor WASM project hosted by a Server project but the app code doesn't run on the server. It runs only on the browser.

If you want to use a JS library on the Server project you need to use **nodejs** and `INodeServices`. You can read this post to know how to use it : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/nodeservices-where-javascript-and-net-meet-back-on-the-other-side/

> [`INodeServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.nodeservices.inodeservices) is now obsolete and there isn't replacement but you can still use it. Or you can choose to use [Javascript.NodeJS](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS) instead.